API Calling Failure after Publishing the .net core API
I have developed MAUI application and .net core API separately. After I published my .net core API on the IIS Server API, mobile application (Android) fails API calls. But in debug mode It worked fine. After I published the API I changed the base URL into a domain name. I'm sure my API is working because I use postman and API tester (for mobiles) to verify it.
Here is my code....
var loginData = new { Username = username, Password = password };
#if DEBUG
    HttpsClientHandlerService handler = new HttpsClientHandlerService();

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler.GetPlatformMessageHandler());
       
#else
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
#endif

client.BaseAddress = new Uri(DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android ? "https://apps.example.com:93/HRA_API1" : "https://apps.example.com:93/HRA_API1");

var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Auth", loginData);

Why my mobile app restrict these api calls even when I testing it on postman works fine. Please help me solve this problem.

Please check the IIS Log to see if there is any request from the Android MAUI application.

And please also check if you have set  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> and <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> in your MAUI Application ?

@JasonPan Thank you for your advice. I checked logs though it does not indicate anything regarding to this. And I have already set up the mentioned permissions.

This means that the app on your Android device doesn't send any HTTP requests. We need to check if http or https is being used? and whether port 93 is allowed on the server.

@JasonPan  I found the issue. We need to change the URL from "https://apps.example.com:93/HRA_API1"  to  "https://apps.example.com:93/HRA_API1//" by adding "/" to the end.

It's a typo issue

yeah it is a typo issue
